# jQuery | String replace does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, str-replace

I have the following script:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var ui_id = id.replace("delete", "hidden");
var am_id = id.replace("delete", "internal");
```

If I do

```
console.log(id);
```

I get the following value:

```
widget-zcircle-2-link_image-remove
```

But the values of **ui_id** and **am_id** are not changing.

The following code :

```
console.log(ui_id);
console.log(am_id);
```

print out in my console the following result:

```
widget-zcircle-2-link_image-remove
widget-zcircle-2-link_image-remove
```

instead of

```
widget-zcircle-2-link_image-hidden
widget-zcircle-2-link_image-internal
```

Is something wrong in my code that I cannot see ?

Kind regards
Merianos Nikos

Comment: remove and delete cant be same

Comment: You have remove in the id and try to replace delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input contains `"remove"` but your code is looking for `"delete"`.

Comment: You are so right !!! I am realy so shy :(. Thanks a lot Jon. I will mark that as answer ! :)

Comment: Συμβαίνει και στις καλύτερες οικογένειες Νίκο. Καλή συνέχεια!

Comment: Έχει δίκιο !! Περιμένω να περάσει λίγη ώρα και θα επιλέξω την απάντηση σου ως σωστή. Ευχαριστώ πολύ και πάλι !!

Answer (score 4):

Replace **`delete` from `remove`** in your replace function... just like

```
var ui_id = id.replace("remove", "hidden");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Talha. I realy feel so shy, was extremelly easy :(